# NSInteger vs 64-bit architecture on iOS

Tags: ios

So, I'm trying to figure out how much I should care about NSInteger vs int.  I don't have a CS degree, so a lot of these type conversion arguments come across pretty obscure.  As best I can tell, the argument is "use NSInteger instead of int in iOS so that eventually if/when 64-bit iOS comes out, your variables will still be the right size to store a pointer."  Fair enough.  Except I'm storing pointers in my ints approximately never.

Suppose I have an int storing a count of magic beans owed to Jack, and another int storing the number of ways to skin a cat, and I'm passing them between functions and writing them to Core Data and whatever, and then Apple releases 64-bit iOS -- what changes?  Why do I care?

Also, if I do care, why isn't that an argument for using int32_t instead of NSInteger?  It seems like *that* would be the way to keep things predictable.

Comment: the number of ways to skin a cat may easily exceed 32 bits. Heck, even 64 bits may not be enough ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: I've never understood the point of NSInteger either ... now if it was an NSObject (like NSNumber) then I could understand it ... Personally I never use NSInteger as it harms my cross-platform compatibility ...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight -- It's not a cat, it's a pooch, and it's screwed, not skinned.  And the screwing was done very early in the development of C when developers left "int" and "short" and then "long" open to interpretation.  And reinterpretation.  And reinterpretation.  And...  Every attempt to straighten it up appears to abuse another pooch.  As I understand it, the Objective-C/Cocoa folks invented NSInteger so they could control the size of that type, independent of other int varieties, so that their declared interfaces could be held harmless should the other definitions change (or vice-versa)

Comment: @Goz What cross-platform compatibility?  NSInteger is explicitly for Obj-C, and other than fringe things such as GNUStep, which also have NSInteger, nothing else uses the language.  For sure if you're using c/c++ use int.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor: Indeed ObjC(++) is ... but you may have noticed you can interact with C/C++ ... I'm not building a class using NSInteger even if it will compile with ObjC(++)...

Comment: In general, if you're using a platform it's best to follow the platform conventions, unless you have a very good reason not to. If you really have to know why you should, in this case it's so that you are sure to be using the same int length as the APIs expect.

Comment: @Goz Sure obj-c can call or include c/c++. But then having NSInteger in the Obj-C parts will not break that. Of course calling c code is common when creating Cocoa apps, without even calling any external APIs. Quartz for example is a C API. Yet most people seem to have no trouble using NSInteger for the Obj-C parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your point about using types from the `<stdint.h>` header of C99 is absolutely valid: these types give you more control over the size of your integral types. The `NS`-prefixed integral types, however, predate the standardization of `<stdint.h>`, hence introducing a parallel set of abstractions.

I use `NS`-prefixed integral types when interacting with Cocoa methods. For example, if Cocoa method returns `NSUinteger`, I declare my variable using `NSUinteger` type as well.

I use `<stdint.h>` types for variables in my program when I need precise control over the size of the stored data. Items that end up in Core Data are in this category.

When the size of an integral type does not matter, for example, when I need a loop control variable in a `for` loop, I use `int`.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation:

- When writing Obj-C code, use `NSInteger`. It then conforms to the frameworks you use. It might change once from `int` to something else (`int64_t`, `long`, ?).
- If writing C/C++ code (portability) obviously **don't** use `NSInteger`.

If you think your variable will exceed `INT_MAX` (a const. check [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)) you might use `int64_t` (when you like to have 32/64 bit flexible code) or `long` (if you don't share memory objects between 32/64 bit versions of your app). Also consider using unsigned types (`uint` `uint64_t`) when you are sure not having minus values in your vars.

Internally: for pointers, don't use `int`. use `void *`